# SCOM Management Pack Tutorial

Tags: .net, monitoring, health-monitoring

I am new to SCOM, but I have read a lot about it and currently installed it in a test environment. What I am really looking for is a good step by step tutorial on how to write a management pack which monitors the health of a .net application. I have found [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb437607.aspx) which can be a start point but I need a more rudimentary guide. Actually an introductory guide which helps monitor a simple application and define client health data suffices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question on technet and got what I want:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/operationsmanagergeneral/thread/6028c093-f2d8-4e7e-aeb4-924f921089a9

Answer (score 2):

Is using...

[Introducing AVIcode](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/avicode.aspx)

...an option?

Comment: Actually is, but what I really care most is that I want a step by step guide to monitor an application.